# convert given time from a given timezone to UTC

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

I have two inputs time 00:00 and timezone 'Asia/Kolkata'

I want to convert this to UTC time like '18.30'

I don't want to add or subtract offsets because it may affect the day light saving

what i did is

```
 local = pytz.timezone ("UTC")
 nativetime = datetime.strptime (setTime,frmt)
 local_dt = local.localize(nativetime, is_dst=None)
 utc_dt = local_dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

but this doesn't change anything, the time is not converted to UTC

Please help

Comment: Of course the time is not converted, you're converting to/from the same time zone!

Comment: Set the pytz timezone to the local timezone, you are currently storing it as 00:00 in UTC time and converting to UTC time

Comment: guys, i am new to python can i get a reference code on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, assuming you're on py3:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 4, 0, 0, tzinfo=tz)
>>> dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 3, 18, 7, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you say you're new to Python, it might be good to skip `pytz` since it's [going to be deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/) with Python 3.9. You can use [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead, which can be replaced more easily with [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html) in Python 3.9.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from dateutil.tz import gettz

# assuming you have something like
dt_naive = datetime.strptime('2020-08-05', '%Y-%m-%d')

# dt_naive has no time zone info, so set it:
dt_aware = dt_naive.replace(tzinfo=gettz('Asia/Kolkata'))

# now you can convert to another timezone using .astimezone:
dt_aware_utc = dt_aware.astimezone(timezone.utc)

# datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 4, 18, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
# -> 5:30 hours behind, which matches dt_aware.utcoffset()
```

Answer (score 0):

@thebjorn gave me the answer

here is what i did

```
def utc_to_local(utc_dt,local_tz):
    local_dt = utc_dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(local_tz)
    return local_tz.normalize(local_dt)


setTime='00:00:00'
setZone='Asia/Kolkata'

datePart = str(datetime.utcnow()).split(' ')[0]
dateTimeUtcStr = datePart+' '+str(setTime)
tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
tz_utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')
dateTimeRef = datetime.strptime(dateTimeUtcStr, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

#local to utc
tzUtc = pytz.timezone('UTC')
local_dt = tz.localize(dateTimeRef, is_dst=None)
utc_dt = local_dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
print(utc_dt)

#utc to local
altTime = utc_to_local(utc_dt,tz)

print(altTime)
```